# How to rotate CGPoint from Landscape to Portrait UIImage orientation?

Tags: swift3, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, cgpoint

I have a UIImageView that I draw a triangle on.  Points "A" `leftPost` & "B" `rightPost` are always static and the same distance from one another.  The "tip" or point "C" is determined by tapping on the UIImageView.  While the image is in portrait mode, I have no problem recreating the UIImageView along with the coordinates of the tapped CGPoint.

However, I need to display the UIImage in landscape mode and represent the same triangle.  How do I "rotate" my coordinates to achieve this?  I am also implying that I am NOT rotating the screen from portrait and landscape.  The app is always in landscape.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let shotGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(shotOnNet))

        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(shotGesture)

        //Enable tapping on screen
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }

    func setupBezierPath(tip: CGPoint) {

        let leftPost = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 50)
        let rightPost = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50)

        bezierPath.move(to: leftPost)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: rightPost)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: tip)
        bezierPath.close()

    }

    func setupShapeLayer() {
        shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
     shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }

    func shotOnNet(_ sender: Any) {

        let shot = (sender as! UITapGestureRecognizer).location(ofTouch: 0, in: imageView)

        setupBezierPath(tip: shot)
        setupShapeLayer()
        imageView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you need to modify the coordinates and not simply apply a rotation transform to the entire `UIImageView`?

Comment: Yes, I'm actually storing the value of the tap gesture in CoreData, so I can recreate the triangles.  The code above is a simplification to show an example.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet. If so can you please share it.